# Display Category in Left sidebar in magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I am going to create one e commerce website. And I chose magento 1.7. But I am new in magento. I Wrote the following code in /app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/catalog.xml
My code is

```
 <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" template="catalog/navigation/left_nav.phtml" />
```

and another page i change the code in left_nav.phtml
/app/design/frontend/default/default/template/catalog/navigation/left_nav.phtml

```
<h2>Browse</h2>
<div class="block">
<ul id="nav_category" class="nav_category">
    <?php foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category): ?>
        <?php echo $this->drawItem($_category) ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLeftLinks') ?>
<?php
$obj = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation();
$store_cats = $obj->getStoreCategories();
$current_cat    = $obj->getCurrentCategory();
$current_cat    = (is_object($current_cat) ? $current_cat->getName() : '');

foreach ($store_cats as $cat) {
    if ($cat->getName() == $current_cat) {
        echo '<li class="current"><a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($cat).'">'.$cat->getName()."</a>\n<ul>\n";
        foreach ($obj->getCurrentChildCategories() as $subcat) {
            echo '<li><a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($subcat).'">'.$subcat->getName()."</a></li>\n";
        }
        echo "</ul>\n</li>\n";
    } else {
        echo '<li><a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($cat).'">'.$cat->getName()."</a></li>\n";
    }
}
?>
```

But it wont displaying category in left side bar.
Anyone please help me.

```
<---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
```

Its start showing on 
I put this line in catalog.xml

```
 <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" template="catalog/navigation/left_nav.phtml" />
```

and this line in left_nav.phtml

```
<h2>Browse</h2>
<div>
<ul id="nav_category">
 <?php foreach ($this->getStoreCategories() as $_category): ?>
 <?php echo $this->drawItem($_category) ?>
 <?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLeftLinks') ?>
```

IT Work.
Thank you all for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open your .phtml page where u want to display category and past this code
load(3)->getChildrenCategories();
?>
 getUrl() ?>">getName() ?> 

paste this code below where left is call

Answer (score 0):

give the reference name like following

```
<reference name="left">
      <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" template="catalog/navigation/left_nav.phtml" />
</reference>
```

and refresh the cache.